# How do I perform a calculation on a column whenever a new sheet is uploaded?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'd like to do a simple calculation every time a new sheet is uploaded to a folder in Google Sheets. The calculation should be automated so the script will recognize a new file and will go to a specific column in it and add 10% of that cell value to the same cell.

Comment: There is no trigger for "a new spreadsheet was created in a folder". What you can do is run a timed trigger, perhaps once an hour, that will loop over all spreadsheets in a folder and perform the calculation.